# Rails route not found even when its present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

My following API route is not found when hit with CURL or POSTMAN client

```
Started POST "/api/users/register_handheld" for 181.74.100.34 at 2017-05-11 11:27:42 +0000
DEBUG: Chewy strategies stack: [2] <- atomic @ /home/deploy/boold/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/chewy-0.8.4/lib/chewy/railtie.rb:17

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/api/users/register_handheld"):
```

But when I run `rake routes`, this URL is present.

```
api_users_register_handheld POST  /api/users/register_handheld(.:format)
                            crowd/api/v1/handheld_users#create {:format=>"json"}
```

This URL actually works if I hit in rails console:

```
app.post "/api/users/register_handheld"
Started POST "/api/users/register_handheld" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-11 11:21:03 +0000
DEBUG: Chewy strategies stack: [3] <- atomic @ /home/deploy/boold/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/chewy-0.8.4/lib/chewy/railtie.rb:17
Processing by Crowd::Api::V1::HandheldUsersController#create as JSON
```

Routes file is

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    scope module: :v1 do

  resources :dashboard, controller: "account/dashboard"

  post '/account/settings/create_notification' => 'account/settings#create_notification'

  post '/users/register' => 'users#create'
  post 'users/register_handheld' => 'handheld_users#create'
  put 'users/update_profile' => 'handheld_users#update_profile'
  post 'users/login' => 'handheld_users#login'
```

NOTE: this repo is Rails Engine

Comment: Add your routes..as I can see, you have versioning namespace..might be u are missing that.. `v1`

Comment: No, @Md.FarhanMemon then the request from the console would fail.

Comment: What line is triggering the error?

Comment: Can you give us a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? If its a rails engine then the engine should be mounted properly in a dummy application.

Comment: Engine is properly mounted as other routes are working fine.

eg: post '/users/register' => 'users#create' is working fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get JSON data from Rails API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911429/cant-get-json-data-from-rails-api)

Comment: Append `.json` to the URLs

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
/api/users/register_handheld.json
```

as you specified format type `json`

Comment: No luck. It's a normal route .json should not be a constraint

Comment: @puneet18 app is on different IP

Comment: @Prem your logs ie Started POST "/api/users/register_handheld" for 181.74.100.34 at 2017-05-11 11:27:42 +0000 shows that ip 181.74.100.34

Comment: @puneet18 yes its hosted on 181.74.100.34 a linode server.  I also checked by running rails console on linode

Comment: But ip not run in browser

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps someone.

Using POSTMAN i accidentally uncheck `Host` Key in headers (POSTMAN autogenerate it each time you send any request). It was a nightmare to find what's the problem until i compared my request with a similiar one and found the missing key.